# Do xml have variables. So some part could be replaced during the runtime?

Tags: xml

I have a xml file that will be copied a lot of times, and there i have a path, that is always the same for one project. Is there a possibility to make a variable that stores the path, so I must replace the path only one time project?

desireable example:

```
var directory = "C:\dir\dir2"

<project>
    <junitreport todir= directory\report>
    </junitreport>
    <junitreport todir= directory\result>
    </junitreport>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ant `build.xml` files support [properties](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#properties) which you can use to define "variables" which you can later use in your `build.xml` file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I found two ways to do it.
Properties:

```
<project>
  <property name="project_directory" value="C:\dir\dir2" />

  <junitreport todir= "${project_directory}\report">
  </junitreport>
  <junitreport todir= "${project_directory}\result">
  </junitreport>
</project>
```

Doctype:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE project [
  <!ENTITY directory "C:\dir\dir2">
]>
<project>
  <junitreport todir= "&directory;\report">
  </junitreport>
  <junitreport todir= "&directory;\result">
  </junitreport>
</project>
```